# Array get 2nd item

Tags: php, arrays

```
foreach($xml->xpath( 'programme[@channel="1"]' ) as $item) {
    if (something) {
        echo "cat.: ".$item->{'category'}. "<br>";}
```

If i have 2x "category" to choose, how to set it to get the second one, not the 1st in the row?

Comment: use something like `if ($first) { $first = false; continue; }` to skip it?

Comment: Add a coutner before the foreach, incrase it in your end of your loop, and if it is not the first, you can get your value.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be to use a counter variable:

```
$i = 0;
foreach($xml->xpath( 'programme[@channel="1"]' ) as $item) {
    if ( $i++ != 1)
        echo "cat.: ".$item->{'category'}. "<br>";
```

However, this will include *every* category after the first.  If you *only* want the second category, you could use the same approach:

```
$i = 0;
foreach($xml->xpath( 'programme[@channel="1"]' ) as $item) {
    if ( $i++ == 2)
        echo "cat.: ".$item->{'category'}. "<br>";
```

Comment: well i am comparing data to the time, so i have: if ($time > $start && $time < $end) {      what now?

Comment: *If i have 2x* what if its just one category ?

Answer (score 0):

This gives you the second category and also ensures that you'll get the first category when there's no second one:

```
foreach ($xml->xpath('programme[@channel="1"]') as $item) {
    if (something) {
        if (isset($item->category[1]) && !empty($item->category[1])) {
            echo 'cat.: '.$item->category[1].'<br />';
        } else {
            echo 'cat.: '.$item->category[0].'<br />';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: unfortunately it won't work for me, still shows the 1st instead of second. I would like to provide the full info: i am getting via simple xml, the part of it here: http://wklej.to/2zmFZ . My php script looks like this: http://wklej.to/13OQB . As it can be seen in xml file there are always two <category> directives provided. My point is to get the second one, instead of the 1st as it is so far. Kind Regards!